# Sentry on supervisor - Error no log file

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, supervisord, sentry

I'm trying to setup a sentry server (getsentry.com). I can run sentry just fine manually as the sentry user. But when I try and run it in supervisor via 'supervisorctl tail sentry-web' I get 'sentry-web: ERROR (no log file)'

The supervisors sentry program specifies using syslog for both regular and error log. I have also tried specifying absolute paths to log files both in the home directory for the sentry user, and under /var/log

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Supervisor: 3.0b2
- Sentry: 7.5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont be able to use the log commands (or fg iirc) when using syslog for output (which we recommend for simplicity).

An absolute path should work fine, but you'll need to confirm that the user supervisor is running Sentry as has write access to the directory.

If you use syslog, you should see output in /var/log/syslog

A good way to test things is to run the command as the user in the foreground (outside of supervisor). Also by default our log verbosity isn't very high (we actually don't do much informational/debug logging at this time), so you're fairly limited on the output you'll get. There is the possibility to change it, but it utilizes Django's LOGGING configuration and we don't yet document this/expose it in a user friendly way.